# Remove unused namespaces from DataContractSerializer output

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

Is there any way to stop the DataContractSerializer from outputting xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" in the first xml tag?  It isn't being used and I am trying to fit my messages under 1KB so they will be delivered by Raw Push Notifications for Windows Phone 7.  I've already gotten it binary serialized and removed all other namespaces.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

-- Edit -- I meant 1K, not 1000K, lol

Comment: That namespace is required if something is nil, are any of your types nullable?

Answer (score 1):

This is not execly  what you ask, but one way to compress the data is to give your members a shorter name

```
[DataMember(Name = "ID")]
 int IdNumber;
```

Comment: "I am trying to fit my messages under 1000KB " and "Any help would be appreciated"

Comment: "Is there any way to stop the DataContractSerializer from outputting xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" in the first xml tag?"